# Как в консольном приложении вводить данные по образцу?

Tags: python, консоль, input

Смысл в том, что у меня есть уравнение (a + b)^2, где неизвестны переменные a и b - их значение задаёт пользователь.
Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь вводил переменные в консоли, то они бы в реальном времени подставлялись на место a и b в моём уравнении.
Должно выглядить так:

```
input >>> (23 + b(на место b, как и на место a пользователь может подставить целочисленное значение)^2
```

При таком раскладе пользователь будет понимать куда и какое число он собирается записывать. Обратите внимание, что весь визуальный процесс должен происходить прямо в консоли. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил:)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 1):

с помощью input не получится вводить по месту. Можно сделать запрос ввода чуть более информативным и удобным, например так

```
ab = input('Для решения уравнения (a + b)^2 \nвведите через пробел значения a b\n')
a, b = ab.split()
a, b = int(a), int(b)
print(f'({a} + {b})^2')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ainp = input("Введите a:")
binp = input("Введите b:")
formula = "(a+b)**2" # формула
formula = formula.replace("a",ainp) #заменить а в формуле на полученное из input число
formula = formula.replace("b",binp) #то же самое, но с b
print("Формула: "+str(formula)) #вывести "сырую" формулу
out = eval(formula) # выполнить код
print("Вывод: "+str(out)) # вывести значение
```

Узнать про eval() - https://proglib.io/p/dinamicheskoe-vypolnenie-vyrazheniy-v-python-funkciya-eval-2020-05-14

Если кодом будет пользоваться много людей, советую прочитать это - https://habr.com/ru/post/221937/
**От этого зависит безопасность ваших данных!**

Надеюсь, понятно ответил!